# "java.lang.Object" cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

> The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right click on project
2. Build path
3. Configure build path
4. Select the Libraries tab, you should see the Java 1.8 jre with an error
5. Select the java 1.8 jre
6. Click the Remove button
7. Add Library
8. Add JRE System Library > Next > workspace default > Finish