# The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

The red hat java [vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) randomly started giving me this warning `The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` on all my files, I've tried to find out how to fix this but I can't find anything about this problem on vscode. I've only found a solution for this problem for eclipse ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560663/java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved)), could anyone tell me what the equivalent of that would be for vscode, or any other way to fix this warning.

Comment: Sounds for a perfectly reasonable question to ask on [their github issue tracker](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues). Maybe it is the same problem as described in [this issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1595).

Answer (score 7):

Just ran `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` and it fixed everything